# How to put text below centered image responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I create a responsive web page with image as background and another image(logo) centered in page.

The problem is that I want to put a text right below the centered image (logo) with a title. I tried to put it using padding-top, but it's inefficient and not very responsive.

I want to responsively put the text below the centered image.

Here is my **code**.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  src: url('assets/font/Raleway-Thin.ttf') format ('ttf');
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  background-image: url('assets/image/bg.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
p {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 60% font-size: 17px;
}
img.ri {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 40%;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
}
img.ri:empty {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  p {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 65%
  }
  img.ri {
    max-width: 75%;
  }
}
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  img.ri {
    max-height: 85%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img class="ri" src="assets/image/logo.png">
  <p>THIS WEBSITE IS CURRENTLY UNDER MAINTENANCE</p>
</body>
```

Comment: check my updated answer. it is working fine as you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, i think this is what you want.

Wrap the `logo` and `text` in a `div e.g: <div class='wrapper'>` and apply css to this class.

**CSS**

```
 .wrapper {
   width:100%;
   text-align:center;
   padding-top:15%;
   position:relative;
 }
```

Here is the modified **Snippet**

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  src: url('assets/font/Raleway-Thin.ttf') format ('ttf');
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  background-image: url('assets/image/bg.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow:auto;
}
.wrapper {
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  top:30%;
  position:relative;
}
p {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
margin-top: 5px;
max-width: 70%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
img.ri {
  max-width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <img class="ri" src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/3498db/fff">
  <p>THIS WEBSITE IS CURRENTLY UNDER MAINTENANCE</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: it's not working, the image at the top and the gap between the text is too wide

Comment: its ok now, have a look.

Comment: Also image is responsive.

Comment: yes the image is become responsive but the position of the image and the text when i resize it, its moving to the top not stay in center horizontally

Comment: ok that issue been solved now, i think its perfect of what you desired. :)

Comment: thanks its working now, but i need to change 'top:50%' at the '.wrapper'

Comment: If you change it to `50%` it won't be in middle of screen because with the `top:50%` the height of the logo and text is combined, so to make it in middle of screen you have to neglect the height of logo and text.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want something like this, try [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uo3j86gn/)

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Raleway';

  src: url('assets/font/Raleway-Thin.ttf') format ('ttf');
}

html, body{
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

body {
  background-image: url('assets/image/bg.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

p{
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  color:#000;
  text-align: center;

  font-size: 17px;
  
}

.center
{
left:0;
right:0;
top:0;
bottom:0;
margin:0 auto;
position:absolute;
 position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<body>
<p class="center">  <img class="ri" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"><br>THIS WEBSITE IS CURRENTLY UNDER MAINTENANCE</p>


</body>
```

Comment: it works for the font, but the image is not responsive

Comment: you can use bootstrap to make responsive image or give it percentage in css

Comment: i add the max-width:100% and its working, but the text and the image wont stay horizontally centered

Comment: Why add `max-width: 100%`?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<body>    
<figure>
<img class="ri" src="assets/image/logo.png">
<figcaption>THIS WEBSITE IS CURRENTLY UNDER MAINTENANCE</figcaption>
</figure>
</body>
```

Comment: nope is not working, the text stay on middle top not below the image

Answer (score 0):

```css
.member {
    display: inline-block;
    width:31%;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}
.name {
    display: inline;
}
.member img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="design-cast">
     <h4>Design</h4>

    <div class="member">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/zmPeyso.png" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="Responsive image" />
        <div class="name">Name Description</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the image not even in the center